# Simultaneous processing of two models on 1 GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I have one GPU.
First, let's assume that the img comes from the camera in real time.
And I have 2 trained pytorch models doing different tasks.
Each model uses img as the same input.
Is there a way to ensure that the GPU inference of model 1 and model 2 are processed simultaneously rather than sequentially?

Note: "Not" Processing one model on multiple GPUs in parallel

Comment: Why don't you execute each one independently when you receive the request/img? You can also [`set_per_process_memory_fraction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65557955/7347631).

Comment: @ndrwnaguib

It's not a memory problem.
I want to do asynchronous GPU inference.
Since this work has to be done in real-time without delay, I want two models to perform each task at the same time and process it again using each output, because delay occurs when the models are performed sequentially.