# CUDA out of memory. ...4.61 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, memory, pytorch

I am trying to limit the amount of GPU reserved by PyTorch. Yolo8 offers `workspace` parameter that limits the PyTorch reserved memory. How can I do it in general (not limited to Yolo8)?
I've tried to add a system variable `CUDNN_CONV_WSCAP_DBG 2048` (additional -> system variables), but I still get

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.52 GiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total
capacity; 4.59 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 4.61 GiB reserved
in total by PyTorch)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49529372/1593077) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force GPU memory limit in PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529372/force-gpu-memory-limit-in-pytorch)